# C - Comparison function - Need explanation

Tags: c, arrays, string, string-comparison

I'm currently reading *[Engineering a Sort Function](http://cs.fit.edu/~pkc/classes/writing/samples/bentley93engineering.pdf)* and  try to understand the following lines about comparison functions:

> To sort an array of len-byte strings with terminal null characters,
>   use the standard string- comparison routine, strcmp: qsort(a, n, len,
>   strcmp); 
> To sort an array of pointers to strings, use strcmp with
>   another level of indirection.
>         int pstrcmp(char **i, char **j) { return strcmp(*i, *j); }

The string comparison is clear, but not comparison for an array of pointers to strings. I think `strcmp(*i, *j)` will just compare the first strings in both arrays but will return 0 (= *equality*) if these strings match. The code won't even look at the strings at the 2nd, 3rd, etc. index.
Does this method really just compare the first string in both arrays or am I missing something?

Comment: What is pstrcmp? I do not know such a function.

Comment: I am not clear what are the types of the arrays in the two cases

Comment: @VladfromMoscow He showed the definition of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think strcmp(*i, *j) will just compare the first strings in both arrays but will return 0 (= equality) if these strings match. The code won't even look at the strings at the 2nd, 3rd, etc. index.

You've misread what this is for. "To sort **an array** of pointers to strings ...". This is about sorting a single array, not more than one array.

Comment: Oh thank you, I really did misread. I thought it was to sort an array of string arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
int cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char* s1 = (const char*)*a;
    const char* s2 = (const char*)*b;

   return strcmp(s1, s2);
}
```

`cmp` function get pointers to two string(char*) which `qsort` wishes to compare not the whole array of strings